# How to using awk & cut

Tags: linux, awk, cut

I don't have experience with awk & cut, please help me with my question
I have command to count total connection to to my server port 80 from per ip address

```
netstat -na|grep ":80" |awk '{print $5}'|cut -d : -f1|sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
      4 173.252.80.117
      4 173.252.80.116
      4 173.252.80.113
      2 173.252.80.119
      2 173.252.80.118
      2 173.252.80.115
      1 66.249.64.170
      1 173.252.80.114
      1 173.252.80.112
```

I have command to list connection status between my server port 80 with per ip address

```
netstat -nat | grep ":80" | grep -v LISTEN | awk '{print $5 "\t" $6}' | sort | uniq -c
      1 192.168.14.91:54008     TIME_WAIT
      1 192.168.14.91:54009     TIME_WAIT
      1 192.168.14.91:54010     TIME_WAIT
      1 192.168.14.91:54011     TIME_WAIT
      1 192.168.14.91:54012     TIME_WAIT
      1 192.168.14.91:54013     TIME_WAIT
      1 192.168.15.82:54071     ESTABLISHED
      1 192.168.15.82:54072     ESTABLISHED
      1 192.168.15.82:54073     ESTABLISHED
      1 192.168.15.82:54074     ESTABLISHED
      1 192.168.15.82:54075     ESTABLISHED
      1 192.168.15.82:54076     ESTABLISHED
```

How do I change my command to make output like :

3 192.168.14.91     ESTABLISHED
  2 192.168.14.91     FIN_WAIT2
  6 192.168.14.91     TIME_WAIT
  6 192.168.15.82     ESTABLISHED
  2 192.168.15.82     SYN_RECEIVED
  6 192.168.15.82     TIME_WAIT

Comment: you never need sed, grep, or cut if you are using awk since awk can do what they can do.

Answer (score 2):

by awk

```
netstat -nat |awk '!/LISTEN/&&/:80/{split($5,a,":");b[a[1] FS $6]++}END{for (i in b) print b[i],i}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
netstat -na |
grep ":80" |awk '{print $5}'|cut -d : -f1|sort | uniq -c
```

to

```
netstat -na |
awk -v OFS='\t' '/:80/{split($5,a,/:/); cnt[a[1]]++} END{for (ip in cnt) print cnt[ip], ip}'
```

and

```
netstat -nat |
grep ":80" | grep -v LISTEN | awk '{print $5 "\t" $6}' | sort | uniq -c
```

to

```
netstat -nat |
awk -v OFS='\t' '/:80/ && !/LISTEN/{split($5,a,/:/); cnt[a[1] OFS $6]++} END{for (ip in cnt) print cnt[ip], ip}'
```

and `| sort -nr` to the ends as you like.